FastApi session cookies and AWS ECS
I have a FastAPI server that creates a user session with the following code:
@app.post("/session")
async def create_session(req: reqs.LoginRequest, response: Response):

    session = uuid.uuid4()
    data = SessionData(session_id=str(session), username=req.username, world_id="1")

    await backend.create(session, data)
    cookie.attach_to_response(response, session)

I deploy the server to AWS ECS. There are two tasks running, serving the same image.
When I try to get the session, it alternates between a correct response, and a 403 forbidden invalid session response.
I might be wrong, but it seems the cookie is being set such that it only works with the ECS task/instance that set it.
What's the correct way to go around this?

Which session backend are you using? If you're using this https://jordanisaacs.github.io/fastapi-sessions/ it seems like it only has an in-memory backend, which would explain why the sessions are only valid on the same instance. Seems like you're expected to create your own database session backend, or perhaps that library is not really usable.

That is indeed what I am using. This is mostly a temporary solution until we get a proper login pipeline implementation, but that's good to know why we're experiencing this. Thanks :)
